# Parsing and formatting JSON array from SQL Datareader JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json

I am populating a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)array from a [datareader](/questions/tagged/datareader)in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). The [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code is here:

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  //
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FurnitureDB"].ConnectionString;
  conn.ConnectionString = connStr;
  conn.Open();
  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.CommandText = "GetLatLongPins_active";
  SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  //var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(datareader);

  //con.Open();
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(dt);
  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
  Dictionary<string, object> row;

  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
      row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
  }

  return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

The array that is returned looks like this:

```
var markers = JSON.parse('[{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true}]');
```

I need to parse it out so that it looks like this for the Google Maps API:

```
var waypts = [{
  location: '34.257179, -119.234190',
  stopover: true
}, {
  location: '34.257179, -119.234190',
  stopover: true
}, {
  location: '40.554306, -81.921422',
  stopover: true
}, {
  location: '40.906651, -97.093629',
  stopover: true
}, {
  location: '29.431261, -97.171709',
  stopover: true
}, ]
```

I have tried a number of variations, if I cut it back to only one piece I can create the result I want, for example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true}');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Location:' + obj.Latitude + ',' + obj.Longitude + ',' + 'stopover:true';
'
```

This produces the output I need for Google Maps

> Location:34.257179,-119.23419,stopover:true

But when I try to do a loop over the data I'm struggling to make it work. One of my attempts looks like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true}', {
  "Latitude": 29.431261,
  "Longitude": -97.171709,
  "Active": true
}]
');


for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  x += obj.Latitude[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

I'm testing by sending the output to an output window.  When I run the code above I get nothing, no output.  I've tried to correlate my example to the many available examples, but haven't had success.  Thanks for any recommendations.

Here is a stack snippet based on the request, I hadn't used that before, but I do see my code is generating an error. That should be helpful.  I'll continue to look at that as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    var x = [];
    var obj = JSON.parse('[{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true}]');


    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      x += obj.Latitude[i] + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where does the C# code stop and the javascript code start? Can you do the (client-side, I assume) javascript as a [StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: I added the stackSnippet in the original post.  It's producing an error which is helpful.  I will review that.

Comment: If you separate your javascript out into the Javascript box of the snippet, then click the Tidy button, there is a syntax error or two that will be immediately apparent. Also, [here's more on JS debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).

Comment: I cleaned up the code snippet a little and I don't get the errors (I had missed a few things in my copy/past), but I still get no output.

Comment: If you are struggling to translate the data into the correct format on the client side, why not return it in the correct format from c#?

Comment: Good point.  I went through and was able to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

Then, if your input is:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true}]');
```

By using:

```
var waypts = obj.map(function(x) {
  return {
    location: x.Latitude + ", " + x.Longitude,
    stopover: true
  };
});
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "location": "34.257179, -119.23419",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "34.257179, -119.23419",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "40.554306, -81.921422",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "40.906651, -97.093629",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "29.431261, -97.171709",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "34.257179, -119.23419",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "34.257179, -119.23419",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "40.554306, -81.921422",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "40.906651, -97.093629",
    "stopover": true
  },
  {
    "location": "29.431261, -97.171709",
    "stopover": true
  }
]
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var obj = JSON.parse('[{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":34.257179,"Longitude":-119.234190,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.554306,"Longitude":-81.921422,"Active":true},{"Latitude":40.906651,"Longitude":-97.093629,"Active":true},{"Latitude":29.431261,"Longitude":-97.171709,"Active":true}]');

  var waypts = obj.map(function(x) {
    return {
      location: x.Latitude + ", " + x.Longitude,
      stopover: true
    };
  });
  console.log(waypts);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that.  It worked perfectly.  Prior to seeing this I was also able to get a workable solution by creating the proper string in C# as suggested by dbc, but this helps me understand the javascript side a little better.